# Can batteries shrink physically in size?

Tags: batteries, lipo

A few days ago I took apart my laptop,an HP BC000nq, with the intention of adding a new 4GB RAM module but I found something intriguing.The battery surface was carved with deep cavities between each cell.At first glance it seems like the battery wrap shrunk against each of the cells body,the battery seems alright it even holds charges.Is this even possible? Should I be worried?

Comment: Unless it is bulging, I wouldn't worry about it. Batteries rarely (or never) implode.

Comment: If it looks like this one, I'd say you're fine.  https://www.amazon.com/Emaks-TE03XL-battery-TE03061XL-15-ax000/dp/B07DPN1FXN

Answer (score 2):

I think that's just heat from usage further shrinking the shrink wrap around the cells.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Funny how that stuff contracts with heat and never expands again until you physically pry it open.

Answer (score 0):

> Lithium-ion cells can swell due to many reasons, but somehow the issue
>   of deep discharge swelling and the related hazards with charging such
>   a battery seem to be widely underestimated.
>
> Common causes of battery swelling include:
>
> - Overcharge conditions which accelerate parasitic reactions between the electrodes and electrolyte, with release of heat and gases.
> - Poor cell quality and design with low anode to cathode stoichiometric ratios, particulate contamination
> - Mechanical damage to electrodes induced either during cell assembly or from the product application
> - Excessive temperatures (Do not leave your cell phone inside your car)
> - Deep discharge of cells

Source: https://www.dfrsolutions.com/blog/why-do-lithium-ion-batteries-swell

While li-ion batteries do swell (when samsung forgot about this they had to recal the galaxy note 8's). Usually the flat cells bulge.

If your battery pack looks like the picture below, the indenation is probably due to the integrated battery management system being shrink wrapped with the battery. The indentation is manufactured like that. 
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the indentation in the pictured battery. Could you highlight it somehow?